# How to make gganimate work after upgrade to R v4?

Tags: r, gganimate

I just upgraded to R 4.0.0 (Mac). Now gganimate doesn't work, and how to fix that is outside my knowledge base.

As a reprex, I simply copied the first example in the gganimate help section:

```
anim <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  transition_states(gear, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()

anim
```

The result is 100 png files in the working directory, but no animation - not as a saved file, nor in the RStudio viewer window.

No error message generated either.

Any help?

Comment: Fwiw, it looks like there are a handful of similar bug reports in the Github repo: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `geom_point()` after `ggplot` call.  The following code

```
anim <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=gear))+
  transition_states(gear, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()

animate(anim , renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

generates this output:

[image: output]

Comment: D'oh! Guess I cut-and-pasted a lil' sloppily. 